# Problem with a query in the Wordpress with NOT IN and NOT BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Have a good day at all. First, I want to apologize for my bad English, but I use Google tranlator to write.
I recently stumbled across a query that's causing me some trouble, and I just can t figure it out. The query is as follows:

```
$query_mq = "SELECT p.ID FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
             LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm1 ON p.ID = pm1.post_id
             WHERE p.post_type = 'sede'
             AND p.post_status = 'publish'
             AND (
                 (pm1.meta_key LIKE 'sale_meeting_%_dimensioni_superficie'
                  AND pm1.meta_value NOT BETWEEN $mq_da AND $mq_a)
             OR p.ID NOT IN
                (SELECT pp.ID FROM $wpdb->posts AS pp
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm2 ON pp.ID = pm2.post_id
                WHERE pp.post_type = 'sede'
                AND pp.post_status = 'publish'
                AND pm2.meta_key LIKE 
               '_sale_meeting_%_dimensioni_superficie' )
             )";
```

The query is likely to work, but the problem occurs whether there are two values in the database that match.

I exported the data, but the SQL file is really too big, so I cut the original query that I've posted to the minimum of the essential to allow the export of only two tables. The zip file for the popular is here: https://galaxypictures.eu/sql.zip . As an example on quotation, I suppose that $mq_da is 101 and $mq_a is 200, the p.ID 31157 got two correlations, that sale_meeting_0_dimensioni_superficie and sale_meeting_1_dimensioni_superficie. Since sale_meeting_0_dimensioni_superficie is 75, and sale_meeting_1_dimensioni_superficie is 150. Only one falls within the research parameters, so the p.ID 31157 appears in the outcome, while I need only because one one is part of the search parameters, then p.ID 31157 does not appear in the results.Thank you
Suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `The query is likely to work` ... you should read about SQL injection and prepared statements.

Comment: Your question is not clear  .. please add the tables schema, a proper data sample  .. your actual result and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Thanks for responding. I changed the original post.